# Isomorphisms between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\left( \mathbb{R}^3\right)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, real-numbers, differential-forms

Consider the oriented euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. Every vector $A \in \mathbb{R}^3$ determines a $1$-form $ω^1_A$ by $ω^1_A(ξ)=(A,ξ), ξ\in \mathbb{R}^3$ *(scalar product)* and a $2$-form $ω^2_A$ by
\begin{equation}
ω^2_A(A,ξ_1,ξ_2)=(A,ξ_1,ξ_2) \text{*triple scalar product*}
\end{equation}
Show that the maps $A \to ω^1_A$ and $A \to ω^2_A$ establish isomoprhisms of the linear space $\mathbb{R}^3$  of vectors $A$ with the linear spaces of $1$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the $2$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then choose an orthonormal oriented coordinate system $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and show that:
\begin{align}
& ω^1_Α=A_1 x_1+A_2 x_2+A_3 x_3 \\
& ω^2_A=A_1 x_2\wedge x_3+A_2 x_1\wedge x_3+A_3 x_1\wedge x_2
\end{align}

I do understand the last two relations, since it can be proved that the set of linear coordinates $\{x_1,...,x_n\}=B$ is a basis for $\left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)^*$, therefore every $1$-form can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the basis, and moreover, I have already proved that every $2$-form can be written as a linear combination of the exterior product of elements of $B$, therefore like a linear combination of $1$-forms , exactly like $ω^2=\sum_{i<j}^n α_{ij}x_i \wedge x_j$.

I am not able to prove the first part, concerning the isomorphisms, plus I cant really see why does it have to be an orthonormal coordinate system. I am guessing just orthogonality will do fine as far as linear independece is concerned.

How can I prove the first part? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for orientations or bases to show that the two given (linear!) maps
$$\nu_1:\ A\ \longmapsto\ \omega_A^1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad \nu_2:\ A\ \longmapsto\ \omega_A^2,$$
are isomorphisms. The spaces of $1$-forms and $2$-forms are of dimensions $\tbinom{3}{1}=3$ and $\tbinom{3}{2}=3$, respectively. So to show that $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ are isomorphisms, it suffices to show that they are injective.

1. If $A\in\ker\nu_1$ then $\omega_A^1=0$, so in particular
   $$\langle A,A\rangle=\omega_A^1(A)=0,$$
   which shows that $A=0$ and hence $\nu_1$ is injective.
2. If $A\in\ker\nu_2$ then $\omega_A^2=0$, so for all $\xi_1,\xi_2\in\Bbb{R}^2$
   $$\det(A,\xi_1,\xi_2)=\omega_A^2(\xi_1,\xi_2)=0,$$
   which shows that $A=0$ and hence $\nu_2$ is injective.

For the relations to hold you *don't* need $\Bbb{R}^3$ to be oriented and you *don't* need $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to be an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. What you *do* need is for $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to be the dual basis to whatever basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ you choose for $\Bbb{R}^n$: If for all $A\in\Bbb{R}^3$ you have
$$\omega_A^1=A_1x_1+A_2x_2+A_3x_3,$$
then in particular for $A=e_i$ you get $\omega_{e_i}^1=x_i$ where $\omega_{e_i}^1(\xi)=\langle e_i,\xi\rangle$ for all $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^3$. This means precisely that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the dual basis to $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$.

When $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the dual basis to $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ then verifying the two relations is a matter of checking that they hold on any basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. This is easiest for $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$; for $A=e_1$ we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_1x_1(\xi)+A_2x_2(\xi)+A_3x_3(\xi)=x_1(\xi)
&=&\langle e_1,\xi\rangle=\omega_{e_1}^1(\xi).\\
&\ &\\
A_1x_2\wedge x_3(\xi_1,\xi_2)+A_2x_1\wedge x_3(\xi_1,\xi_2)+A_3x_1\wedge x_2(\xi_1,\xi_2)
&=&x_2\wedge x_3(\xi_1,\xi_2)\\
&=&\begin{vmatrix}x_2(\xi_1)&x_3(\xi_1)\\ x_2(\xi_2)&x_3(\xi_2)\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{vmatrix}
 1&0&0\\
 x_1(\xi_1)&x_2(\xi_1)&x_3(\xi_1)\\
 x_2(\xi_2)&x_2(\xi_2)&x_3(\xi_2)
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=&\omega_{e_1}^2(\xi_1,\xi_2),
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $\xi,\xi_1,\xi_2\in\Bbb{R}^3$, and the same argument works for $e_2$ and $e_3$, of course.

Comment: A great job indeed. Thank you again. I maybe ask introductory questions, regarding these concepts, but it the first time I deal with them. Bare with me, I am now entering the $1$ and $2$ differential forms :)

Comment: Asking such questions is only natural, it means you're giving the material proper critical thought. Especially since the material seems to be presented to you in a rather obfuscating way, for example by adding conditions of orientation and orthonormality which are completely unnecessary, and by *not* introducting you to exterior algebras and their universal properties. And I find it a nice exercise to present the material in a clear and concise way, so I'm glad to hear it helps. So don't hesitate to ask more :)

Comment: Well, I guess it has to do with the books I am studying from. Would you suggest any book specifically for differential forms on an introductory level?